# Prove that A+B is invertible given the conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am fighting with this problem:

$$Let\ A,B \in\;\mathbb{R^{nxn}}\ be\ symmetric.\ In\ addition\ \lambda_{amin}(A) \ge 2\ and\ \lambda_{amax}(B) \le 1.\ Show\ that\ the\ matrix\ A+B\ is\ invertible.\ $$

I should prove that and still I easily find matrices A and B that will make the argument not hold.
$$i.e.\ A = \begin{bmatrix}5 & 7\\2 & 3\end{bmatrix} and\ B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the $det(A+B)=0$ and, thus not invertible.

I should somehow use this theorem: $\lvert \delta A \rvert < 1/\lvert A^{-1}\rvert$

I cannot figure out why "A+B is invertible" would be true, if I can find matrices A and B that will prove otherwise?

Comment: Your $A$ is not symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you're not using symmetric matrices in your example.

**A proof for symmetric matrices.**

If $A+B$ was not invertible, there would exist $u \neq 0$ such that $(A+B)(u) = 0$.

Hence $\Vert A(u) \Vert_2 = \Vert B(u) \Vert_2$. But that can't be as this leads to the contradiction:
$$2 \Vert u \Vert_2 \le \lambda_{\textrm{amin}}(A) \Vert u \Vert_2 \le \Vert A(u) \Vert_2 = \Vert B(u) \Vert_2 \le \lambda_{\textrm{amax}}(B) \Vert u \Vert_2 \le 1\Vert u \Vert_2$$

Comment: Oh of course those are not symmetric matrices.. Thank you for your remarkably clear answer!